# Unable to read outlook emails when powershell script is run as job

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have a Powershell script to read emails and it works fine when i run it from PS console. When i try to run it as schedule job using Task scheduler the script isnt working. I tried running the job under my username(admin), still it doesnt work. Can someone help me identify this issue.

```
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $mapi.Folders.Item("test@mydomain.com").Folders.Item("Inbox")
$inbox.items|%{        
    if($_.UnRead -eq 1){
           $subject=$_.subject
           $_.Unread = $false
           Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.mytest.com/api' -Method 'Post' `
            -ContentType 'application/JSON' `
            -Body  $subject
   }
}
```

Comment: MAPI profiles are per-user.

Comment: Office interop usually doesn't work in a non-interactive session.